# Connecting a ESP8266 GPIO Input to a 4.2V

Tags: voltage-divider, esp8266, logic-level

I am following this great article on building a low power sensor using ESP8266. The author (Gadjet) connects the GPIO12 pin to a LIPO through a 10K resistor. I am not sure if this a great way to do, this can fry the MCU, whose Vcc is at 3.3V.

In my limited knowledge, this could be solved using a voltage divider or logic level shifter. What could a better solution to such a problem ?

[ESP12F Sensor](https://gadjetsblog.blogspot.com/2022/03/the-many-versions-of-wireles-door.html)

Comment: current fries, not voltage, and there's nowhere near enough current in 0.9v/10k to damage the GPIO, which are also designed (though not officially guaranteed) to be 5v tolerant anyway. A voltage divider would waste power the whole time it was connected, even if the MCU were off.

Comment: btw, this would be much better designed to simply power the MCU through the reed switch, so that it's zero-current standby. I have devices like that operating on 2 AA batteries (yeah, under 3.3v) that have lasted 3 years so far. The key is to use ESP-NOW to phone home instead of wifi; this lets you boot and send and sleep in ~200ms instead of several seconds with wifi, greatly extending the responsiveness and battery life. All you need is the reed, an ESP01, and a battery clip, much much simpler and cheaper.

Comment: that is exactly what the circuit is doing, you are suggesting to control the ESP power via reed, and the circuit is controlling the EN pin of LDO. The circuit draws less than 10uA thats a lot of battery backup

Comment: i'm saying you don't even need any LDO, PCB, extra components, or an 18650 that self-drains in 2 years. I just use smaller and cheaper ($1 per 2) AAs, an ESP01 ($1), and a reed switch ($0.50); so for $2.50 and 10 mins of work (4 solders and some taping), I get a button/switch/sensor that lasts >5 years. I don't see how making it more complex, more expensive, larger, and more work provides any advantages. K.I.S.S. i say, but to each their own.